# What does `TypeError: core_2.EventEmitter is not a function` actually mean?

Tags: typescript, angular, typescript1.7

Trying to implement output emitter here:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {EventEmitter} from "angular2/core";
import {steps} from "../wizard/steps";

@Component({
  selector: 'wizard-step-1',
  outputs: ['suggestStep'],
  templateUrl: 'app/components/wizard-step-1/wizard-step-1.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/components/wizard-step-1/wizard-step-1.css']
})
export class WizardStep1 {
  suggestStep = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {}
  proceed () {
    this.suggestStep.emit(1);
  }
}
```

That one works. However, when i try passing an enumerable to the `.emit(enum)` like this:

```
this.suggestStep.emit(steps.step2);
```

Browser fails with:

```
EXCEPTION: EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of WizardStep1!.
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: core_2.EventEmitter is not a function
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: core_2.EventEmitter is not a function
    at new WizardStep1 (http://localhost:4200/app/components/wizard-step-1/wizard-step-1.js:27:40)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:1372:20
    at Injector._instantiate (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11917:19)
    at Injector._instantiateProvider (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11859:21)
    at Injector._new (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11849:19)
    at InjectorInlineStrategy.instantiateProvider (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11609:28)
    at ElementInjectorInlineStrategy.hydrate (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13234:20)
    at ElementInjector.hydrate (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12882:22)
    at AppViewManagerUtils._hydrateView (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9662:31)
    at AppViewManagerUtils.hydrateViewInContainer (http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:9638:12)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object] in [steps.step1 in Wizard@4:3]
```

I don't see the connection between the change and the error. Do you?

Comment: That normally means that it's not finding `EventEmitter` in `angular2/core` which is weird because it is in core and it works for you from there. What contains `steps`? Did you make sure to export `steps` in the other file? I can't reproduce it in my env, can you reproduce it in a plnkr?

Comment: can you post the main html page ( with js includes and systemsjs config )

Comment: @EricMartinez here's the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/6IRPSBe9Sn30zpOWMUzS?p=preview

Comment: @MouradZouabi here it is: https://paste.ee/p/5WPQZ

Comment: @Birowsky it worked for me when I added `const` in `steps.ts` : `export const enum...`